# How to get a JS DOM element in Knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, dom-events

Given the following Knockout:

```
$(self.domElement()).on('click', '.item.one-option button,.panel-heading', function () {
    var panel = $(this);
    // How can I get the DOM element of the click event?
}
```

In a previous example I used function `(item, event)`, and then `event.target`, but that seems to not be working in this case.

Any idea why? And what would work?

Comment: In your example code there is no sign of Knockout... only jQuery... can you extend your question with some additional info how Knockout comes to this picture?

Comment: event.target should work actually. Are you getting an error, or some unexpected element as the event.target? Which element does `self.domElement()` refer to?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(self.domElement()).on('click', '.item.one-option button,.panel-heading', function (event) {
    var panel = $(this);
    var dom = event.target;// How can I get the DOM element of the click event?
}
```